# NSArray coming back as null when called from NSNotificationCenter

Tags: cocoa, nsmutablearray, nstableview, nsnotificationcenter

I have an NSMutableArray being saved with NSUserDefaults, when appLaunched is called the array returns null but when called by any other function it returns what is in the array.  Anybody know what's happening?

```
- (id)init
 {
[super init];
theArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
theArray = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"TheArray"];
if(!theArray) {
    theArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
} else {
    theArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:theArray];
};

// NSLog(@"%@", theArray);
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:theArray forKey:@"TheArray"];
// NSLog(@"Is saving");

return self;
}


 -(IBAction)addNewProcess:(id)sender
 {
     NSString *newProcess = [theField stringValue];
     [theArray addObject:newProcess];
     [theField setStringValue:@""];
     NSLog(@"%@", theArray);
     [theTable reloadData];

 }

 -(IBAction)removeProcess:(id)sender
 {
     int listRow = [theTable selectedRow];
     NSLog(@"%d", listRow);
     if (listRow < 0) return;
     [theArray removeObjectAtIndex:listRow];
     [theTable reloadData];
 }

 -(IBAction)save:(id)sender
 {
     NSLog(@"%@", theArray);
     int count = [theArray count];
     NSLog(@"%i", count);
     [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:theArray forKey:@"TheArray"];
     NSLog(@"Is saving");
  }

 - (NSInteger)numberOfRowsInTableView:(NSTableView *)tableView
 {
     return [theArray count];
 }

 - (id)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView 
 objectValueForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn 
             row:(NSInteger)row
 {
     return [theArray objectAtIndex:row];
 }

 - (void)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView 
    setObjectValue:(id)object 
    forTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn 
               row:(NSInteger)row
 {
     [theArray replaceObjectAtIndex:row
                               withObject:object];
 }

 -(void)appLaunched:(NSNotification *)note
 {
     NSLog(@"%@", theArray);

 }


 @end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't synchronize your NSUserDefaults.
Every time you use `[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:someObject forKey:@"someKey"];` you have to use `[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];` afterwords.